# How can I load data from Firestore in my Jetpack Compose project?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I have this project that I'm migrating to compose and I can't load the data from Firestore in the TextField. With the view system I could reference it and it uploaded automatically but with compose I'm unable to load. Below is the compose page and the FirestoreClass.

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

            FirestoreClass().loadUserDataOnProfile()

                return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                ReiDoFifaTheme {

                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(16.dp)
                        ) {
                            Image(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(top = 24.dp, bottom = 24.dp)
                                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_user_place_holder),
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                            TextField(value = /*TODO*/ , onValueChange = { /*TODO*/ })
                        }
                    }
                }
```

```
    fun loadUserDataOnProfile(){
        firestore.collection(USERS)
            .document(getCurrentUserID())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                val loggedUser = document.toObject(Player::class.java)
                ***
       }
```

I had a function *** called from on addOnSuccessListener that filled my views with the data on ProfileFragment. How do I do it?

Comment: Hey Henrique! I think this article, [How to display data from Firestore using Jetpack Compose](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-49ee736dc07d), might help you achieve that.

Comment: Hi Alex, I checked your article and I did step by step with the source code but I'm getting this error ``` error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.google.firebase.firestore.Query cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements BaseApplication_GeneratedInjector``` I'm struggling to fully understand DI and Hilt but I got everything annotated with Provides and Inject as in your example project

Comment: Be sure you have all dependencies in place with the exact same version as mine and all the right annotation. Make also sure to have the correct AppModule file, as in the repo.

Comment: I started a new project with the exact same estructure as yours, only changed the Products data class with an user data class. Then I copied and pasted both gradle files and I keep getting the same error, saying that the Query cannot be provided without an Inject ou Provides. Any idea why?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I cannot be much of a help. I think you should post a new question, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: After many attempts, I got by specifying the return type : Query on the appModule. I saw that this was missing from my imports compared to yours

Comment: Good to hear that you make it work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Storing the new data to Kotlin Flow APIs

```
 fun loadUserDataOnProfile() : Flow<LoggedUser> = callbackFlow {
    firestore.collection(USERS)
        ...
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            val loggedUser = document.toObject(Player::class.java)
            offer(loggedUser)
        }
    awaitClose { /* unregister firebase listener here */ }
 }
```

Then:

```
    ...
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            val user: LoggedUser by  FirestoreClass().loadUserDataOnProfile().collectAsState(initial = /*DefaultLoggedUser*/)
            ReiDoFifaTheme {
               ...
                        TextField(value = user.name , onValueChange = { /*TODO*/ })
                    }
                
            }
```

Note: But for better, you should combine with the ViewModel